# Android TV switch HDMI input port programmatically

Tags: android, sony, television

I would like to ask you, experienced programmers, if there is a way to switch HDMI input port programmatically from an app installed directly on a TV Sony Bravia. Let's say, on app startup the TV switches it's input to i.e. HDMI3. Is there a common API in Android, or is the function vendor-specific?

Comment: Are you talking about an Android TV itself or an Android TV box switching the input of the TV it's connected to?

Comment: If it's the second, that's an already built in feature, but it requires your TV be compatible with HDMI-cec. Most modern tvs are compatible but it might not work with really cheap hdmi cables.

Comment: Hi, thank you for a super fast reply :) I'm talking about the TV itself. It's a SONY kdl-75w855c with Marshmallow 6.0.1

Comment: I'm not going to post as an answer, because I've never tried to do anything like this personally, but this might be what you're looking for: https://source.android.com/devices/tv/

Comment: So it does look like there is an api in place

Comment: OK, thanks. I'm a complete newbie in development for Android TV so I have absolutely no idea of how the access to the  inputs is managed by the system. I'll take a look at the TIF. Thank you very much once again :)

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?