# Android TV - Switch to HDMI input programatically

Tags: android, kotlin, android-tv, keyevent, television

Is there a way to switch to an HDMI input programmatically on Android TV? I.e. a Smart TV, not a separate box.

What I was trying is to send a key event like this:

```
# `someButton` is a button on the `activity_main.xml`

val inputConnection = BaseInputConnection(someButton.rootView, true);
inputConnection.sendKeyEvent(
    KeyEvent(
        KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN,
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TV_INPUT_HDMI_4,
    )
)
inputConnection.sendKeyEvent(
    KeyEvent(
        KeyEvent.ACTION_UP,
        KeyEvent.KEYCODE_TV_INPUT_HDMI_4,
    )
)
```

Running this has no effect. Other keys like `KEYCODE_BACK` work as expected, so I assume this functionality can only send key events to the app, not the host device itself.

For reference, running the following via adb from my computer works:

```
adb connect MY_TV
adb shell input keyevent 246
```

But of course I don't have permissions to run `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arrayOf("/bin/sh", "-c", "input keyevent 246"))` from within the app.

For reference, what I tried so far:

- Found this old post asking the same question, but no answer: [Android TV switch HDMI input port programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42910789/android-tv-switch-hdmi-input-port-programmatically)
- Got the idea with `sendKeyEvent` from here, but as mentioned did not work: [How can I send key events in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13026505/how-can-i-send-key-events-in-android)
- From the above post, I also unsuccessfully tried the `exec("input keycode 246")` and `instrumentation.sendKeyDownUpSync(...)`. It did not work, but as I understand it, those need special privileges anyway.